# aws codebuild buildspec.yml issue

Tags: aws-codebuild

i have 2 services in clients/ directory. the structure of node js build artifacts is following

```
clients/service1/dist/images/
clients/service1/dist/assets/
clients/service1/dist/index.html

clients/service2/dist/images/
clients/service2/dist/assets/
clients/service2/dist/index.html
```

i have 2 artifact buckets - bucket1, bucket2 and i need to have same structure in these buckets, so in root dirs:

bucket1:

```
/images/
/assets/
/index.html
```

bucket2:

```
/images/
/assets/
/index.html
```

my `buildspec.yml` is the following:

```
post_build:
    commands:
      - cd ./clients/
artifacts:
  files: 
     - 'dist/*'
  base-directory: 'service1*'
  discard-paths: yes
  secondary-artifacts:
    service2_artifact:
      files:
        - 'dist/**/*'
      base-directory: 'service2*'
      discard-paths: yes
```

in codebuild project i have `path = "/"`, `name = "/"`

i got following error:

> *CLIENT_ERROR Message: no matching base directory path found for service1**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 artifacts:
  files:  
   - './**/*'
  base-directory: 'clients/service1/dist'
  discard-paths: no
```

this config works